# Using distinct to return list of unique arrays, not list of unique strings

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection like this:

```
{
  "letters": ["a", "b"]
},
{
  "letters": ["b", "a"]
},
{
  "letters": ["a", "c"]
},
{
  "letters": ["c", "a"]
},
{
  "letters": ["b"]
}
,
{
  "letters": ["a"]
}
```

The query:

```
db.getCollection("collection").distinct("letters")
```

returns:

`["a", "b", "c"]`

**Update:**

Considering the answer, i am now stuck at this aggregation pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "letters": {
        $exists: true,
        $ne: null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$letters",
      
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      letters: {
        "$addToSet": "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
])
```

This returns:

```
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "letters": [
      ["a", "b"],
      ["b", "a"],
      ["a", "c"],
      ["c", "a"],
      ["b"],
      ["a"]
    ]
  }
]
```

What i want to get instead, is a list of distinct arrays (distinct in the sense of the array as a set):

`[["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["b"], ["a"]]`

Is that possible with mongo?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this aggregation pipeline. I'm not sure it's the best way to do it though. The idea is to sort letters arrays first so that the `$addToSet` accumulator groups `["b", "a"]` with `["a", "b"]` and `["c", "a"]` with `["a", "c"]`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$letters"
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "letters": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      letters: {
        "$push": "$letters"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      letters: {
        "$addToSet": "$letters"
      }
    }
  },
])
```

Comment: thank you, unfortunately that does not exclude redundant sets. this will return [a,b] as well as [b,a], but it should return just one of the arrays.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Your comment clarified your question. See if it resolves your issue.

Comment: Unfortuantely, that still keeps the redundant lists. so [a,b] is listed as well as [b,a]. Is that related to the fact that these are lists? That letters provides a list of lists.

Comment: At this point the last step needed is, how can i filter from a list of lists by set definition the redundant lists?

Comment: Look at this playground. It does not keep the redundant list. https://mongoplayground.net/p/AYN7yxnAF14